# Using skipLocationChange, how can I guard against the back button?

Tags: angular

I have followed standard proceedure for creating a `CanDeactivate` Guard and have done the setup required for it mostly following the [Official Guide](https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes)

I am using `skipLocationChange` so my URL does not change when routing.  When I press back, I leave the application.

At this point I would like to capture and display a simple dialog "Are you sure?".

I want this to apply to the whole application and therefor I created a dumb root route by wrapping my existing routes like so:

```
[
   {
     path: '',
     canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard];
     children: [
         ...
     ]
   }
]
```

Back on my `app.component.ts` I have setup the `canDeactivate` method but I do not see it being triggered.

I feel it is my routes that are wrong or that I may be missing something related to `skipLocationChange` or perhaps I am just naive in my approach?

I would appreciate any advice.